# How is beamer's {frame} title optional, yet in braces (not brackets)?

Tags: beamer, optional-arguments, frame-title

It dawned on me that the title in `beamer`, which is provided for in curly braces, is optional!  Help me to understand this.  Normally, optional arguments are supplied in square brackets.  As I show on slide 1 of my MWE, optional arguments can be finicky and will screw up if the optional argument itself contains optional `[]` data. (Note that, in the MWE, `\xyz` is a macro that ignores its optional argument and just outputs the mandatory argument.)

The beamer `frame` title suffers none of these problems, and can process an argument that contains `[]` options.

And yet, when an embraced `frame` title is omitted, as in slide 2 of my MWE, the following first letter of `frame` text is not taken as the 1-letter title.  So `frame` is able to differentiate between an embraced `{title}` and `generic slide text`.  In essence, the braces on the title are serving as the optional argument delimiters.

On slide 3 of my MWE, I give the `\meaning` of `\frame`, which might help unravel the mystery of how `beamer` can use a curly-braced item as an optional argument.

Am I missing something simple?  Please help me to understand how this works.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\xyz[2][]{#2}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title is in braces, but optional! \xyz[\xyz{DOES~NOT}]{WORKS}}
Here is text after title.

Optional arguments can be tricky.  For example,

take \textbackslash xyz macro:

.\xyz{WORKS with no optional argument}.

.\xyz[\xyz{DOES~NOT}]{WORKS with optional argument}.

.\xyz[\xyz[ignoreme]{DOES~NOT}]{WORK when optional argument has []}.

\bigskip
The problem is an optional argument within an optional argument.  
But that problem did not apply to the title (where an optional argument 
was processed).
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Here is text after no title is specified.  

Note that the ``H'' was not taken as a title, 
implying that the title, within braces, is optional.

\bigskip
\textbf{How does this work?!}

The title is an optional argument in curly braces,
not square brackets.  It can process optional arguments within the title.

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Help me to understand this, if this is where the magic is:

\bigskip
\meaning\frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but did you try `\xyz[{\xyz[Some content]{DOES~NOT}}]{WORKS}`? The inner `[]` pair must be 'protected'

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I haven't tried that, but the point stands that a "normal" optional argument needs special care to avoid stupid stuff like brackets within brackets, for which the title of `frame` is immune, because it doesn't use bracket delimiters.  And the real question isn't how to protect optional arguments (though that's good to know), but how `beamer` accomplishes an optional argument in braces.

Comment: I agree with that -- did you have a look into `beamer.cls`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  I'm not sure I'm up to that at "Oh'dark thirty" where I sit `;^)`.  Perhaps tomorrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bottom line is that this is a design decision. To understand what is going on, we need to look at the technical detail.

When Leslie Lamport wrote LaTeX, he decided that as a user having a difference between optional and mandatory arguments was a 'good thing'. He did that by using the `{` ... `}` pair for mandatory arguments and the `[` ... `]` pair for optional ones. However, other people writing LaTeX code can use other conventions.

In LaTeX, the characters `[` and `]` have TeX category codes 'other'. In contrast to `{` and `}`, which are 'begin group' and 'end group', respectively.  TeX does brace matching when grabbing an argument inside `{` ... `}` (a LaTeX mandatory argument) as the rules for 'begin'/'end' group tokens are clear: they *must* balance. On the other hand, TeX does not do that for `[` ... `]` as they are just 'other' tokens. LaTeX2e implements optional arguments using some look-ahead code (to find a `[`) and what is called a delimited argument

```
\def\foo[#1]{% Code here
```

When TeX looks for an argument surrounded by tokens in this way, it does it in a 'lazy' sense. Thus

```
\foo[[bar]]
```

will grab `[bar` as `#1` and leave the second `]` 'dangling'.

It is possible to add additional code to do matching of `[` ... `]` tokens: `xparse` does this. The 'cost' (lines of code) is too high to have been realistic when LaTeX2e was released but is now perfectly acceptable. Thus commands produced using `xparse` do not have the issue with nested square brackets.

In the `beamer` case, Till Tantau uses some look-ahead code for `{` rather than `[`. It's slightly more tricky to do this, but it's is quite workable if commands do not need to be 'expandable'. There are a few minor issues with verbatim slides (the look-ahead is a bit of a pain!), but other than that the reason to not favour Till's approach is that it's not at all obvious reading the code which arguments are required.

Comment: Note that LaTeX's not the only format using `[` ... `]` and `{` ... `}` for different things. ConTeXt uses sqaure brackets for arguments which are not typeset: the same restrictions on nesting apply.

Answer (score 4):

It is only a hint, but the mechanism of using the same kind of braces in different meanings is well-known in basic LaTeX. In

```
\begin{picture}(a,b)(c,d)
```

`(a,b)` are mandatory, `(c,d)` optional. The trick is the following:

```
\long\gdef\picture#1{\pictur@#1}
\gdef\pictur@(#1){%
  \@ifnextchar({\@picture(#1)}{\@picture(#1)(0,0)}}
```

The construction in `beamerbaseframe.sty` is similar:

```
  \def\beamer@checkframetitle{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
  \def\beamer@inlineframetitle#1{%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\frametitle{#1}\framesubtitle}{\frametitle{#1}\relax}%
```

but `(`  is replaced by `\bgroup`.

Comment: Why do the contents of the argument need be not expandable, but the delimiter can be?

Comment: I'm sorry for you that I chose to give Joseph the acceptance.  His answer put things in a larger perspective.  But I really appreciate you tracking down the chunk of relevant code where I can see with my eyes what is happening.  Thanks again.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes For me it is also a better answer. It remains that I am still proud that I could add at least a bit to the knowledge of so advanced user as you.